# Why state management is missing on AWS ElasticSeacrh Kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I have deployed elastic search and Kibana on my local and I am able to perform stack management operations on the local cluster.

ElasticSearch : elasticsearch-7.11.1-windows-x86_64
Kibana: kibana-7.11.1-windows-x86_64

State ManagementL

[image]

Index Life CycleManagement

[image]

Now I want to set up an index roll-up job on my AWS Managed ElastciSearch service, but on AWS deployer service on Kibana, these options are missing.

ElasticSearch : 7.4
Kibana: Kibana 7.4.2

Note: ILM has been introduced in version 7.1.2 so its not about version mismatch. Please refer:
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html#:~:text=ILM%3A%20Manage%20the%20index%20lifecycleedit,%2C%20resiliency%2C%20and%20retention%20requirements](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html#:%7E:text=ILM%3A%20Manage%20the%20index%20lifecycleedit,%2C%20resiliency%2C%20and%20retention%20requirements).

[image]

As per AWS documentation the steps to set up index rollup is as follows:

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/rollup.html

```
To get started, choose Index Management in Kibana. Select Rollup Jobs and choose to Create a rollup job.

Step 1: Set up indices
Set up the source and target indices. The source index is the one that you want to roll up. The target index is where the index rollup results are saved.

After you create an index rollup job, you can’t change your index selections.

Step 2: Define aggregations and metrics
Select the attributes with the aggregations (terms and histograms) and metrics (avg, sum, max, min, and value count) that you want to roll up. Make sure you don’t add a lot of highly granular attributes, because you won’t save much space.

Step 3: Specify schedules
Specify a schedule to roll up your indices as it’s being ingested. The index rollup job is enabled by default.

Step 4: Review and create
Review your configuration and select Create.
```

But none of this is available on my cluster. What am I missing here, is AWS documentation incorrect or Did I done something horrible while creating the cluster?

Regards

Note: I have upgraded the AWS es domain to the latest version: 7.10. Stil stack management feature is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short: You cannot use ILM feature on AWS Managed Elastic Search Service.**

Index Lifecycle Management (ILM) is a free feature which is licensed under the Elastic license [1]. As such, it is only available on Elastic Cloud or to Elasticsearch users that have downloaded Elasticsearch from the Elastic website and are managing their cluster on their own.

Please refer: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=309180

```
Hey richbolen70,

Anurag here, a product manager on Elasticsearch Service on Elastic Cloud - the only service from the creators of Elasticsearch and Kibana.

Index Lifecycle Management (ILM) is a free feature which is licensed under the Elastic license [1]. As such, it is only available on Elastic Cloud or to Elasticsearch users that have downloaded Elasticsearch from the Elastic website and are managing their cluster on their own.

We don't have plans to make it available on the Amazon Elasticsearch Service.

With Elastic's Elasticsearch Service we also allow you to take ILM a step further by allowing you to set node attributes when deploying Elasticsearch in a hot-warm architecture [2] (super powerful for logging and security).

If you're interested, you can give our Elasticsearch Service a try for free [3].

[1] https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/licenses/ELASTIC-LICENSE.txt
[2] https://www.elastic.co/blog/deploying-a-hot-warm-logging-cluster-on-the-elasticsearch-service
[3] https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch/service
```

Answer (score 0):

As per aws [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/rollup.html), you need ES version 7.9 or above to use Index rollups

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Let me upgrade the cluster.

Comment: Upgraded the cluster to 7.10.2 but still stack management is not visible.

Comment: option for "index rollups" is available in "Index management" tab and not in "stack management"

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: Hi Ajinkya, please refer :  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=309180 , YEs I was interested in rollup but my ultimate goal was to set up and define Index Life Cycle Management for my Clsuster using Kibana. Seems due to  Elastic Search licensing, AWS cannot make this service available to end-user for managed service.

Comment: AWS ES provides "Index State Management (ISM)" similar to ILM from v6.8 and above. Please check document - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/ism.html